# change form variable at onchange event

Tags: html, flask, flask-wtforms

I got variable `myvar` in my wtf-form.
I would like to set it's value upon the user selects an option in the dropdown list, w/o the need to add a button/input for the user to confirm his selection. 
So far, I am not able to have a POST event triggered in views.py whenever the user selects an option.

Moreover, setting `form.myvar` as I do below doesn't actually do anything, and the alert message won't fire either.

My flask template code:

```
  <!-- extend base layout -->
{% extends "base.html" %}
<script>
$('#sel_id').change(function() {
    window.alert(5 + 6);
});
</script>
{% block content %}
<div>
<form action="{{ url_for('compile') }}" method="POST">
    <dl>              
        <select id="sel_id">            
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </dl>
</form>
</div>
<script type=text/javascript src="{{
  url_for('static', filename='jquery.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write a piece of JavaScript or jQuery to handle this.

```
$('#sel_id').change(function() {
    var = 4;
});
```

Also, you will want to name your variables something other than `var`, which is keyword. Name it something more descriptive.

Comment: shouldn't this be ".onchange" ?

Comment: "This method is a shortcut for .on( "change", handler ) in the first two variations, and .trigger( "change" ) in the third."

https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: I tried your suggestion on https://jsfiddle.net/1kqzymgo/ and it seems that alert message is not fired when select option is changed. I didn't know how to demonstrate that with flask on jsfiddle, so i did something very basic.

Comment: The code I wrote is in jQuery. You had your Javascript set to VanillaJS. You also don't need to wrap the code in a function.

See my fork: https://jsfiddle.net/vqs0nh71/1/

Comment: This indeed works when i try it jsfiddle; however, it doesn't work for me in my flask app. Any idea why? I have added my flask template code.

Comment: I download jquery from https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js; and updated my code as updated above. still nothing happens!

Comment: as for the VanillaJS; i have tried that too, actually it was my first attempt; but it seems not to have an effect as well; my flask terminal also doesn't show any activity, so checking the select option doesn't seem to result in a POST activity.

Comment: Instead of an alert, try `console.log('yay, it works');` and read your console. 

Have you looked to see if you have any Javascript errors in your console that might be interfering? 

At the risk of asking an obvious question, you said you downloaded jQuery. Did you include it in your `<head>`? Is it referencing the right path? To check, view the page source and click on the jQuery link. It should open the library in your browser.

Comment: OMG; your are my saver. "view the page source" showed me my faults; I had an extra bracket in my function definition.